# Finding out which app is using my library

Tags: ios

Assume, I have a iOS library used by many applications. I like to find out which app end up integrating my library without APP noticing it. What would be the best way to do this? I am looking for a way to query app name string, company or some other similar identifiers using standard iOS APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `NSBundle's mainBundle` to get the data from the app. Then send a network request in one of the methods frequently used in the library (initializer for example) with that information. This is not nice to do though since the developers would expect the full control of their own application. There are always ways to see if an application are doing network requests it shouldn't do. Users (programmers) would probably also select another library without the surveillance "feature".

I'd strongly advice you to NOT implement such a "feature". You would shoot yourself in the foot doing it.

But to answer your question partly; All relevant data can be fetched from the mainBundle:

```
NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSString *appDisplayName = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
NSString *majorVersion = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```